# beamer: Top-aligning columns within a top-aligned frame

Tags: beamer, lists, vertical-alignment, columns

According to section 3.10 of the `beamer` manual, the `t` option top-aligns either every frame (when used as a class option) or a single frame (when used as optional argument of a `frame` environment). According to section 12.7, `t` can also be used to top-align the columns of a `columns` environment (a multi-column area within a frame). However, I didn't succeed to combine the two tasks, i.e. to top-align columns within a top-aligned frame. Did I miss something? How can the correct alignment be achieved?

Note: For columns, there's also a `T` option that (quoting section 12.7) should be tried *"[i]f strange things seem to happen in conjunction with the `t` option"*. Adding `T` to the second column comes close to the desired result, but doesn't achieve it (the second column is positioned somewhat higher than the first column).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Frame title}
  \begin{columns}[t]
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{itemize}
      \item First column, first item
      \item First column, second item
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}% Alternative A doesn't work
%     \begin{column}[T]{0.5\textwidth}% Alternative B comes close
      \begin{itemize}
      \item Second column, first item
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: Thanks to Stefan for posting a workaround solution. I'm still interested in why such a workaround is necessary resp. why top-aligned columns work within centered frames by default. Is this a bug in `beamer`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could set `\topsep` and `\partopsep` to zero. Here's a definition of an itemize version with this in mind, achieving vertical top alignment. It's similar to a solution I remember which Uwe Lück posted some time ago to a mailing list.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{myitemize}{%
   \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
   \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}
   \renewcommand*{\@listi}{\leftmargin\leftmargini \parsep\z@ \topsep\z@ \itemsep\z@}
   \let\@listI\@listi
   \itemize
}{\enditemize}
\makeatother   
\begin{document}    
\begin{frame}[t]{Frame title}
  \begin{columns}[t]
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{myitemize}
      \item First column, first item
      \item First column, second item
      \end{myitemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{myitemize}
      \item Second column, first item
      \end{myitemize}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that this also works when you have some figure (via `includegraphics`) in the second `column`: using `myitemize` lets the option `T` work as one would expect (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400369/behavior-of-top-alignment-of-columns-in-beamer))

Answer (score 30):

**Update**

This known bug was solved [some time ago](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/78). There is no need for workaround solutions or including special lines of code in preambles.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Test Columns}
\begin{columns}
\column{.5\linewidth}
First Column
\begin{itemize}
\item First Item First Item First Item First Item
\item Second Item Second Item Second Item Second Item
\end{itemize}
\column{.5\linewidth}
Second Column
\begin{itemize}
\item First Item First Item First Item First Item
\item Second Item Second Item Second Item Second Item
\end{itemize}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Test Columns}
\begin{columns}
\column{.5\linewidth}
First Column
\begin{itemize}
\item First Item First Item First Item First Item
\item Second Item Second Item Second Item Second Item
\end{itemize}
\column{.5\linewidth}
Second Column
\begin{itemize}
\item First Item First Item First Item First Item
\item Second Item Second Item Second Item Second Item
\end{itemize}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

works as expected

[image]

**Original answer**

This problem was reported (issue #78) at [Github beamer development repository](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/). The suggested solution was:

> I know how to fix it, and it's quite easy, but I'm not sure if it will break something else. If you need the fix badly, replace lines 256--260 in `beamerbaseframe.sty` which read:

```
\def\beamer@initfirstlineunskip{%
  \def\beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip{%
    \vskip-\partopsep\vskip-\topsep\vskip-\parskip%
    \global\let\beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip=\relax}%
  \everypar{\global\let\beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip=\relax}}
```

> with

```
\def\beamer@initfirstlineunskip{}%
```

Its state is still 'on hold'.

Instead of modifying beamer files, we can include some lines in our preamble.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{t}[true]{% top
  \beamer@frametopskip=.2cm plus .5\paperheight\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax%
  \beamer@frametopskipautobreak=\beamer@frametopskip\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskipautobreak=\beamer@framebottomskip\relax%
  \def\beamer@initfirstlineunskip{}%
}
\makeatother   
\begin{document}    
\begin{frame}[t]{Frame title}
  \begin{columns}[t]
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{itemize}
      \item First column, first item
      \item First column, second item
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{itemize}
      \item Second column, first item
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This does not work when one column has more lines than the other

Comment: I ended up using https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116707/230922 instead

Answer (score 12):

It may be worth trying `minipage`, instead of creating the custom modifications in the preamble, especially if it is going to be something that is not used a lot of times:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Frame title}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \vspace{0pt}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item First column, first item
            \item First column, second item
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \vspace{0pt}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Second column, first item
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

where the `\vspace{0pt}` is there just to give LaTeX a common reference to align the contents in both `minipage`.

Comment: for top-aligned columns which start in the *middle* of a page (rather than as a first element after slide header), this is the correct solution!