# Top alignment of itemize in columns of beamer

Tags: beamer, lists, vertical-alignment, columns

I do not know what is wrong but the top alignment of the itemize environments in the two columns are different. I could not find a reason for this.

```
\documentclass[10pt,fleqn,t]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{titre}
\begin{columns}%
\begin{column}[t]{0.45\textwidth}%
text text text
\begin{itemize}
\item 1
\item 2
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}[t]{0.45\textwidth}%
text text text
\begin{itemize}
\item 1
\item 2
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Beamer: Top-aligning columns within a top-aligned frame](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16447/beamer-top-aligning-columns-within-a-top-aligned-frame)

Comment: Although the linked solution is surely not ideal (although it works.)  It seems there's something wrong with `beamer` here.

Comment: I've added an answer to linked solution with a possible fix for this problem. I repported it to beamer's developers some month ago and they proposed a still 'on hold' solution.

Comment: @Ignasi the solution you give to the other question doesn't actually work for this problem. So maybe this question isn't a duplicate after all.

Comment: @Alan, please look at my answer here. I think it works. I'm using beamer-development version with miktex 2.9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar behaviour was reported as [Issue #78](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/78) in Beamer's development repository and also
in question [Beamer: Top-aligning columns within a top-aligned frame](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16447/beamer-top-aligning-columns-within-a-top-aligned-frame). The temporary solution proposed at former is equivalent to include some lines into your preamble

```
\documentclass[10pt,fleqn,t]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}

\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{t}[true]{% top
  \beamer@frametopskip=.2cm plus .5\paperheight\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax%
  \beamer@frametopskipautobreak=\beamer@frametopskip\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskipautobreak=\beamer@framebottomskip\relax%
% \def\beamer@initfirstlineunskip{%
%   \def\beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip{%
%     \vskip-\partopsep\vskip-\topsep\vskip-\parskip%
%     \global\let\beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip=\relax}%
%   \everypar{\global\let\beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip=\relax}}
  \def\beamer@initfirstlineunskip{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{titre}
  \begin{columns}%
    \begin{column}[t]{0.45\textwidth}%
      text text text
      \begin{itemize}
        \item 1
        \item 2
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}[t]{0.45\textwidth}%
      text text text
      \begin{itemize}
        \item 1
        \item 2
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]