# Items in columns are not top aligned the same

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment, itemize, columns

If I'm using itemize inside a beamer column, the items are not the same way top-aligned as the items without a column.
I want the symbols of both items in the images to be at the very same place.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Heading 1}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item top aligned item nr. 1
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Heading 2}
  \begin{columns}[t]
    \column[t]{.5\textwidth}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item item nr. 2, which is lower than item nr. 1
      \end{itemize}
    \column[t]{.5\textwidth}
      the other column
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Item Nr. 1 and Item Nr. 2 should have their symbols at the same position.]

Comment: Duplicate? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22916/top-alignment-of-itemize-in-columns-of-beamer?rq=1

Comment: Being a duplicate or not, you should try with the same kind of text in both columns: itemize+itemize or text+text, not itemize+text.

Comment: Before paragraphs is only `\parskip`, but before itemize are `\topsep + \parskip + \partopset`. This cause observed difference in aligning of both kind of text on top of columns. A simple hack is to put negative vertical skip before itemize (which compensate this difference).

Comment: Maybe I didn't describe it right: I want the symbols of the items on slide 1 and slide 2 to be on the exact same position - the problem is not the other column on the right...

what negative skip would I have to add to compensate this spacing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why consecutive slides (which are not displayed at the same time) cannot be different, but ...

As it seems that `columns` environment introduces some vertical space before its contents, the first slide could be written inside a `columns` environment with one column. This way both spaces will be equivalent.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Heading 1}
  \begin{columns}[t]
    \column[t]{\textwidth}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item top aligned item nr. 1
  \end{itemize}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Heading 2}
  \begin{columns}[t]
    \column[t]{.5\textwidth}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item item nr. 2, which is lower than item nr. 1
      \end{itemize}
    \column[t]{.5\textwidth}
      the other column
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]