# Problem with top alignment in beamer columns

Tags: beamer, graphics, floats, minipage, columns

I am trying to place two images in top of two columns in a `columns` environment, in a beamer presentation.

The first column consists of one image on top and a enumeration list bellow the image.

The thing is that I want the column to start at the top of the frame, which isn't happening in my case. My code is

```
\documentclass[slidestop,compress,mathserif,11pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemebars}
\usepackage[bars]{beamerthemetree}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setbeamercovered{higly dynamic}
\usetheme{Ilmenau} % Beamer theme v 3.0
\useoutertheme[subsection=true]{smoothbars}%Beamer Outer Theme-circles on top
\usefonttheme{serif}
\useinnertheme{circles}

\begin{document}
        \section{Εισαγωγή}
\begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Nuclear Propulsion}
        \begin{columns}
                \begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
                        \begin{figure}[t]
                        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{AtomicSubmarine}%\vspace{0.5cm}
                        \end{figure}
                        \tiny{\begin{enumerate}
                                \item Item1$\rightarrow$ Conclusdion
                                \item Item2$\rightarrow$ Conclusdion
                                \item Item3$\rightarrow$ Conclusdion
                                \item Item4$\rightarrow$ Conclusdion
                                \item Item5$\rightarrow$ Conclusdion
                                \item Item6$\rightarrow$ Conclusdion
                        \end{enumerate}}
                        %\begin{minipage}[t]{0.99\textwidth}
                                %\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{AtomicSubmarine}
                        %\end{minipage}
                \end{column}\hfill
                \begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
                        %\begin{minipage}[b]{0.99\textwidth}
                        \begin{figure}[t]
                                \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{SubmarineSnorkel}
                        \end{figure}
                        %\end{minipage}
                \end{column}
        \end{columns}
        %\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
                %\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{SubmarineSnorkel}
        %\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The output of this code is

[image]

It is clear that a few lines upper would be ideal, as the real presentation frame, states!

[image]

I've tried to remove the `figure` environment, to use `minipage` but  the right image is aligned with the list, resulting in a very bad format. One solution is to remove the `frametitle` but I'm afraid I need it...

Another idea is to use `\vspace{-1cm}` but I am not sure if this is the optimum solution...

Any ideas on that?

Comment: Duplicate question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16447/beamer-top-aligning-columns-within-a-top-aligned-frame

Answer (score 39, accepted):

See section 12.7 (*Splitting a Frame into Multiple Columns*) of the `beamer` manual:

> `t` will cause the first lines of the columns to be aligned. Default if global option `t` is used.
>
> `T` is similar to the `t` option, but `T` aligns the tops of the first lines while `t` aligns the so-called baselines of the first lines. If strange things seem to happen in conjunction with the `t` option (for example if a graphic suddenly “drops down” with the `t` option instead of “going up,”), try using this option instead.

I see you commented out some `minipage` environment. No need to use `minipage` in conjunction with `column`, because the latter uses the former internally. You should be able to achieve any multiple-column layout you want with just `columns` and `column` environments, without (explicitly) using `minipage`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[slidestop,compress,mathserif,11pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemebars}
\usepackage[bars]{beamerthemetree}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setbeamercovered{higly dynamic}
\usetheme{Ilmenau} % Beamer theme v 3.0
\useoutertheme[subsection=true]{smoothbars}%Beamer Outer Theme-circles on top
\usefonttheme{serif}
\useinnertheme{circles}

\begin{document}
\section{Εισαγωγή}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Nuclear Propulsion}
    \begin{columns}
      \begin{column}[T]{0.48\textwidth}
      \vspace{0pt}%
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{AtomicSubmarine}
        \vspace{1em}
        \tiny
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Item1$\rightarrow$ Conclusdion
            \item Item2$\rightarrow$ Conclusdion
            \item Item3$\rightarrow$ Conclusdion
            \item Item4$\rightarrow$ Conclusdion
            \item Item5$\rightarrow$ Conclusdion
            \item Item6$\rightarrow$ Conclusdion
        \end{enumerate}
      \end{column}\hfill
      \begin{column}[T]{0.48\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\columnwidth]{SubmarineSnorkel}
      \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Now it's working like a charm!!! Thank's!

Comment: You can use `figure` and `table` in `beamer` without problems (in fact, if you want to have captions (which I don't like much but it is sometimes required), it's useful to have the possibility to use `figure` or `table`) since `beamer` internally deactivates the floating mechanism.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina In my experience, `figure` and `table` modify the vertical spacing, though, which is a pain when you're trying to achieve precise positioning of the elements on your frame. But alright, I'll modify my answer accordingly.