# Behavior of top alignment of columns in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, vertical-alignment, columns

I have two `columns` in a top-aligned `frame` which I want to be top-aligned as well. One `column` is an `itemize` environment, the other `column`  includes a graphic via `includegraphics`.

I read in the `beamer` manual that the `T` option should be used when strange things happen. This is why I preferred to have `T` as a default option, but that is not a good idea as it does *not* result in proper top-alignment.

See the following example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% dummy text macro
\newcommand{\mylipsum}{bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{A frame with 2 \texttt{columns}: \texttt{itemize} + \texttt{figure} }
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item first item \mylipsum
                \item second item \mylipsum
                \item third item \mylipsum
                \item fourth item \mylipsum
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{test_image.png}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]{A frame with 2 \texttt{columns [T]}: \texttt{itemize} + \texttt{figure} }
    \begin{columns}[T]
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item first item \mylipsum
                \item second item \mylipsum
                \item third item \mylipsum
                \item fourth item \mylipsum
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{test_image.png}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Surprisingly, the case with the option `T` results in worse top-alignment, as can be seen when comparing the two figures (adding `T` actually shifts the `columns` down...).

[image: page 1 without the <code>T</code> option]
[image: page 2 with the <code>T</code> option]

Why is the option `T` shifting the `columns` down and what am I missing here?

I am not sure if it plays a role, but here are the versions of beamer and XeTeX I am using (according to the output when compiling with `xelatex`):

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015/Debian)
[...] 
LaTeX2e <2016/02/01>
[...]
Document Class: beamer 2015/01/05 3.36 A class for typesetting presentations (rcs-revision 8a39122e1f63)
```

**Edit**: I do not think that this question is a duplicate of [that one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16447/beamer-top-aligning-columns-within-a-top-aligned-frame) as suggested: First of all, none of the answers solves the problem presented here and the problem here is specifically about the weird behavior of the `T` option.

Comment: Applying the changes as suggested by the user Ignasi does not work. It is also not a duplicate in my opinion as I am specifically asking about the weird behavior using the option `T`

Comment: @Schweinebacke using `myitemize`, everything works indeed as expected: the option `T` shifts the list upwards (and it is aligned with the figure), thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `\begin{columns}[T]` the columns are only top aligned relative to their top edges. But below the top edge of an `itemize` environment their is still a vertical distance of either `\topsep` or `\partopsep`. So you not only need to align the `columns` but also remove this distance. [Stefan's answer to the linked question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16449/9057) defines an environment `myitemize` to do so:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% dummy text macro
\newcommand{\mylipsum}{bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{myitemize}{%
   \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
   \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}
   \renewcommand*{\@listi}{\leftmargin\leftmargini \parsep\z@ \topsep\z@ \itemsep\z@}
   \let\@listI\@listi
   \itemize
}{\enditemize}
\makeatother   

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{A frame with 2 \texttt{columns}: \texttt{itemize} + \texttt{figure} }
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item first item \mylipsum
                \item second item \mylipsum
                \item third item \mylipsum
                \item fourth item \mylipsum
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=.7\textheight]{example-image}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]{A frame with 2 \texttt{columns [T]}: \texttt{itemize} + \texttt{figure} }
    \begin{columns}[T]
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item first item \mylipsum
                \item second item \mylipsum
                \item third item \mylipsum
                \item fourth item \mylipsum
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=.7\textheight]{example-image}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]{A frame with 2 \texttt{columns [T]}: \texttt{myitemize} + \texttt{figure} }
    \begin{columns}[T]
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \begin{myitemize}
                \item first item \mylipsum
                \item second item \mylipsum
                \item third item \mylipsum
                \item fourth item \mylipsum
            \end{myitemize}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=.7\textheight]{example-image}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: top aligned image and list]